# How to sort a struct with strings using its integers in C?

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I'm coding a program in C that should rank countries by its gold medals in the olympic games.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _Table {
    char *country;
    int amnt, gold, silver, bronze;
} Table;

char *arrayAlloc(int size) {
    char *array;
    array = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    return array;
}

void readTable(Table *ptr) {
    char buffer[100], *cpyPtr, *savePtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->amnt; ++i) {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';  
        ptr[i].country = strtok_r(buffer, " ", &savePtr);
        ptr[i].country = strdup(ptr[i].country);            
        cpyPtr = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savePtr);
        ptr[i].gold = strtol(cpyPtr, &cpyPtr, 10);
        cpyPtr = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savePtr);
        ptr[i].silver = strtol(cpyPtr, &cpyPtr, 10);
        cpyPtr = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savePtr); 
        ptr[i].bronze = strtol(cpyPtr, &cpyPtr, 10);
    }

}

void printTable(Table *ptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->amnt; ++i) {
        printf("%s %d %d %d\n", ptr[i].country, ptr[i].gold,ptr[i].silver, ptr[i].bronze);
    }
}

int compare(const void *p, const void *q) {
    int l = ((Table *)p)->gold;
    int r = ((Table *)q)->gold; 
    return (r - l);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int N;      // Amount of lines
    scanf("%d", &N);
    getchar();
    Table tab[N];
    tab->amnt = N;
    tab->country = arrayAlloc(100);

    readTable(tab);

    qsort(&tab->gold, tab->amnt, sizeof(Table), compare);

    printTable(tab);

    free(tab->country);
    return 0;
}
```

Input example:

```
4
BRA 3 4 5
USA 23 76 34
CHN 23 54 12
GER 10 20 23
```

Expected output:

```
USA 23 76 34
CHN 23 54 12
GER 10 20 23
BRA 3 4 5
```

What I'm getting:

```
BRA 23 54 12
GER 23 76 34
CHN 3 4 5
USA 10 20 23
```

As you can see it seems to "sort" it somehow. However it is far from what I need to accomplish.
I've already tried to modify the compare() function, but without success.
What am I possibly missing here?

Comment: The variable `tab` is an *array*. It's *this* array you should sort, not the first elements `gold` member. The expression `tab->gold` is equal to `tab[0].gold`.

Comment: Your [mcve] is full of bugs, your question become too broad.

Comment: Thank you @Stargateur, next time I'll follow the instructions from this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
qsort(&tab->gold, tab->amnt, sizeof(Table), compare);
```

The first two arguments should be a pointer to your array (`Table tab[N];`) and the number of elements in the array (`N`), i.e.:

```
qsort(tab, N, sizeof(Table), compare);
```

You did have the correct number of elements in `tab->amnt`, but the start pointer `&tab->gold` doesn't point to the beginning of the table, but in the middle of the first element, so `qsort` can't work correctly.

---

Also, you have functions with loops like this:

```
void printTable(Table *ptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->amnt; ++i) {
```

Which means that you're carrying the size of the array in its first member. That seems odd, and means the array member 'amnt' is redundant in all but the first member of the array.

But if the array gets sorted, the first array member is no longer the first, and `ptr->amnt` doesn't contain the correct size any longer.

Better change `printTable` to

```
void printTable(Table *ptr, unsigned size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
```

and call it with

```
printTable(tab, N);
```

Same for `readTable`.

---

I'm also not sure what the purpose of this is:

```
tab->country = arrayAlloc(100);
```

You're preallocating space pointed to by the `country` pointer in the first array member, but in any case `readTable` allocates space for `country` with `strdup` to all array members.

---

You might also want to consider checking the value or `N` entered by the user, or allocating the memory for `tab` via `malloc`. Now `tab` is allocated on the stack, which may cause the program to crash if the user enters some number large to cause a stack overrun.

Also, since you don't check the return values of the `strtok_r` calls in `readTable`, the program will crash if the user gives malformed input.

Comment: There are still other issues as well

Comment: @Stargateur, well, they sort of work, as long as the sort doesn't. But you're right, I only looked at the sorting step first, that seemed to be the issue based on the example output.

Comment: Thank you @ilkkachu, it worked fine after your suggested modifications. Also, I did not know I can't pass ptr->amnt this way. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one issue in your code.

First if all you your `tab` would be better if allocated dynamically.

```
Table* tab = malloc(sizeof(Table)*N);
```

Variable-length array are only supported by c99 and later versions and some C11 implementation might not support them too if `__STDC_NO_VLA_` is defined (Check C11 standard 6.10.8.3)

Secondly, everything which iterates on `tab` has to know `tab`'s size which's `N` that you have to pass around as for instance in

```
void readTable(Table *ptr, const int N) {
    char buffer[100], *cpyPtr, *savePtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {...
```

Finaly `qsort` need to be called as follows:

```
 qsort(tab, N,sizeof(Table), compare);
```

The following will produces the expected output (note that I have not checked for any other issues):

```
typedef struct _Table {
    char *country;
    int amnt, gold, silver, bronze;
} Table;

char *arrayAlloc(int size) {
    char *array;
    array = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    return array;
}

void readTable(Table *ptr, const int N) {
    char buffer[100], *cpyPtr, *savePtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';  
        ptr[i].country = strtok_r(buffer, " ", &savePtr);
        ptr[i].country = strdup(ptr[i].country);            
        cpyPtr = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savePtr);
        ptr[i].gold = strtol(cpyPtr, &cpyPtr, 10);
        cpyPtr = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savePtr);
        ptr[i].silver = strtol(cpyPtr, &cpyPtr, 10);
        cpyPtr = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savePtr); 
        ptr[i].bronze = strtol(cpyPtr, &cpyPtr, 10);

    }

}

void printTable(Table *ptr, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%s %d %d %d\n", ptr[i].country, ptr[i].gold,ptr[i].silver, ptr[i].bronze);
    }
}

int compare(const void *p, const void *q) {

    return ((Table *)p)->gold<((Table *)q)->gold;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int N;      // Amount of lines
    scanf("%d", &N);
    getchar();
     Table* tab = malloc(sizeof(Table)*N);


    readTable(tab,N);
    printTable(tab,N);
    qsort(tab, N,sizeof(Table), compare);

    printTable(tab,N);

    free(tab);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
BRA 3 4 5
USA 23 76 34
CHN 23 54 12
GER 10 20 23

USA 23 76 34
CHN 23 54 12
GER 10 20 23
BRA 3 4 5
```

Comment: Why should `tab` be dynamically allocated?

Comment: Consider `qsort(tab, N, sizeof *tab, compare);`.  No need to look back to `tab` definition to see if `sizeof(Table)` is correct.  Also `Table* tab = malloc(sizeof *tab * N);`, just like code used the size of the object rather than the size of the type in `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);`

Comment: BTW, `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';` can be exploited by a user entering a _null character_ as the first character read by `fgets()`.  Suggest `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';`

Comment: I personally think that the code is much clearer when `sizeof` is used with an explicit type.  Regarding the dynamic allocation, I've edited the answer. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues; yet the main two are the following:

In `qsort(&tab->gold, tab->amnt, sizeof(Table), compare)`, you do not pass the begin of the array (as neccessary), but a pointer to a data member of the first element in the array. This means that the pointer passed has a particular offset to the begin of the array and will point almost in the "middle" of the first element. As `qsort` will exchange elements (i.e. memory chunks of the size provided) relative to the pointer you provide to `qsort`, each object may get "split" with unexpected and weird results then (very likely yielding undefined behaviour as well).

Second, you use `tab->amnt = N`, which is equivalent to `tab[0].amnt = N`, i.e. it sets `amnt` only for the first entry. If you then sort the array, the first entry may be replaced by another one, which does not have set `amnt` to a specific value. So your `print`-function, which again relies on `amnt` being in the first element, will count wrong.

So write `qsort(tab, N, sizeof(Table), compare)` and manage the size of the array outside the elements, i.e. introduce a separate parameter `size`, that is then passed to the `print`-function.

Maybe there are other issues as well, but these two are the most suspicious ones to me.